# Import * as not working as expected in node

Tags: node.js, npm, xlsx

I want to use the `xlsx` module for reading and writing to xlsx files, so I installed `xlsx` by running `npm install xlsx` and I followed a tutorial where it was mentioned that:

```
// Requiring the module 
const reader = require('xlsx') 
  
// Reading our test file 
const file = reader.readFile('./test.xlsx')
```

It was working fine, but I was using another module that wasn't a CommonJS module, so I used:

```
import reader from 'xlsx';

const file = reader.readFile('./test.xlsx');
```

It is also working, but my question is: I am able to use anything in place of `reader` and still able to access the method `readFile`. E.g.:

```
import anyRandomWord from 'xlsx';

const file = anyRandomWord.readFile('./test.xlsx');
```

NOW THE CASES THAT ARE NOT WORKING:

1. The official site says that:

> The module also ships with `xlsx.mjs` for use with import:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';
```

when I use:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';

const file = XLSX.readFile('./test.xlsx');
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot access file ./test.xlsx
    at read_binary (file:///home/shivam/Others/Translate/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.mjs:3234:8)
    at readSync (file:///home/shivam/Others/Translate/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.mjs:23811:69)
    at Module.readFileSync (file:///home/shivam/Others/Translate/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.mjs:23851:9)
    at file:///home/shivam/Others/Translate/translate.js:4:19
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12)
```

when I use:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const file = XLSX.readFile('./test.xlsx');
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: XLSX.readFile is not a function
    at file:///home/shivam/Others/Translate/translate.js:4:19
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12)
```

Please tell me why the above cases are working with any random name in import and the below ones are not working.

I have added `"type":"module"` in `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I use
>
> ```js
> import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';
>
> const file = XLSX.readFile('./test.xlsx');
> ```
>
> I get the error
>
> > Error: Cannot access file ./test.xlsx

As mentioned [in the doc](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs#esm-import) regarding usage of the `xlsx/xlsx.mjs` module version:

> The `mjs` version does not automatically load native node modules, so they must be added manually:
>
> ```js
> import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
>
> /* load 'fs' for readFile and writeFile support */
> import * as fs from 'fs';
> XLSX.set_fs(fs);
> ```

---

> I am able to use anything in place of reader and still able to access the method readFile

...and:

> when I use
>
> ```js
> import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
>
> const file = XLSX.readFile('./test.xlsx');
> ```
>
> I get the error
>
> > TypeError: XLSX.readFile is not a function

The `xlsx` package has a [*default* export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import), which you can import with any name you want, as you figured out initially (i.e. `import anyRandomWord from 'xlsx'`).

But when you [import the namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#namespace_import) (i.e. `import * as XLSX`), that default export is now a property of your namespace, i.e. you should now do `XLSX.default.readFile()`:

> The default export available as a key called `default`.

Comment: The mjs version does not automatically load native node modules, so they must be added manually:
I am new to js, which module to add here manually in this case?

Comment: The `fs` module as shown in above code sample. If your usage is more complex (stream, old formats), import the other 2 as shown in the linked doc.